# Wildfly not starting

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

We are not able to start wildfly service. The error shown is "It can not find the file specified" but it will not show which file it is not able to find.

Also, it was working fine and suddenly it stopped working. Any idea anyone?

Comment: Please add more details as in what is not working?

Comment: not able to start Wildfly service itself from Windows services

Answer (score 0):

We have been able to solve this issue. There was a key in registery which was pointing to wildfly-service.exe and had double quotes around it. We removed the double quotes and were able to start wildfly successfully after that.